# Convert UTF-8 to Chinese Simplified (GB2312)

Tags: c#, encoding

Is there a way to convert UTF-8 string to Chinese Simplified (GB2312) in C#. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards
Jyothish George

Answer (score 9):

The first thing to be aware of is that there's no such thing as a "UTF-8 string" in .NET. All strings in .NET are effectively UTF-16. However, .NET provides the `Encoding` class to allow you to decode binary data into strings, and re-encode it later.

[`Encoding.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert.aspx) can convert a byte array representing text encoded with one encoding into a byte array with the same text encoded with a different encoding. Is that what you want?

Alternatively, if you already have a string, you can use:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312").GetBytes(text);
```

If you can provide more information, that would be helpful.

Comment: Is there also a 'C' function available?

Comment: @godlyblade: I have no idea what you mean, I'm afraid. If you're asking for Unicode encoding support in the C programming language, that would be entirely different question... I haven't done anything like that in C.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
public string GB2312ToUtf8(string gb2312String)
{
    Encoding fromEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312");
    Encoding toEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    return EncodingConvert(gb2312String, fromEncoding, toEncoding);
}

public string Utf8ToGB2312(string utf8String)
{
    Encoding fromEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Encoding toEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312");
    return EncodingConvert(utf8String, fromEncoding, toEncoding);
}

public string EncodingConvert(string fromString, Encoding fromEncoding, Encoding toEncoding)
{            
    byte[] fromBytes = fromEncoding.GetBytes(fromString);
    byte[] toBytes = Encoding.Convert(fromEncoding, toEncoding, fromBytes);

    string toString = toEncoding.GetString(toBytes);
    return toString;
}
```

[source here](http://www.cnblogs.com/anjou/archive/2011/11/28/2266479.html)